# Text after iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been looking for a bit and all i find on this topic is on text displayed after broken iframe, what i want to do however is to actually show a text bellow an iframe set at 90% height, like this:

[image]

I want to show some text on the white area, that is a screenshot of how the browser displays my iframe code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<iframe src="https://link.com/" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:90%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
</html>
```

I played around a bit placing text after the iframe closing tag and the text wouldn't show, i'm guessing that what i have to do is to put the iframe within a div, and the another div bellow, but how would i do this?

I've just begun to learn a few days ago.

Answer (score 3):

1. Place the `<iframe>` in an element (I used a `<figure>`) that is `position`ed `relative`.
2. `position: absolute` for the `<iframe>` and any other elements inside the `<figure>` ( I logically chose `<figcaption>`).
3. By default `<iframe>` is `display: inline` change that to `display: block;` and give it a relative height (I give it `height: 70%` wand `width: 100%`).
4. Give `<figure>` an explicit height that will fit the `<iframe>` and `<figcaption>` enough room vertically (I gave `<figure>` `height: 70vh;`).
5. `<figcaption>` is also `width: 100%` and takes the remaining vertical space with `height: 30%`.

**Snippet**

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <figure>
    <iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
    <figcaption>This is an iframe to www.example.com</figcaption>
  </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px;` from the frames styling. That takes it out of normal flow and causes it to appear in the same position as the content that follows it.

Comment: Tried it, but removing position:fixed; breaks the iframe and it no longer resizes accordingly, i just want a 10% space left at the bottom for the text to be on
http://i.imgur.com/2IcH4lX.png